# 24v DC input sense

Tags: switches, dc

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fin3ON.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a device (a card reader) which operates on 5V DC. The card reader has another power input (a secondary input) which accepts 5V DC. Now I need to make a detection of DC voltage system which will check the presence of 24V dc and supply the 5v DC to this secondary power input. Can any one please guide me on a way I could make a solid state DC switch which will pass on the 5V DC to the secondary power input when 24V DC is present.

I am checking out on using transistor to do this but don't know what would happen if I give 24V DC to the base of a transistor.

Comment: The AUX power input specifies max amp to 700mA. The 5v source is 1A. Thanks. The additional circuit to interface 24v will be enclosed inside a single plastic box hosting the device itself. ps. Its a plastic box which contained chocolates earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a circuit as follows to detect the 24V being ON and then gate on the +5V.

[image]

This circuit will switch the 5V input to the output when the 24V input reaches about 22V. It is necessary to add the 10uF capacitor because an unfiltered full wave rectified AC waveform would be switching the NPN on and off with each half cycle of the AC voltage.

If you need to supply a load larger than the ~200mA that I have simulated via the 25 ohm load resistor you would need to select a PNP transistor with a higher current rating than the 2N4403 shown. If your load is in the quite a bit higher it may be necessary to use a heatsink on the transistor OR you could substitute a low Rds-on PFET in place of the PNP.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this now. One question, Will it be safe to use a 1W 30K resistor? The 24v input is approx 1~2 A DC.

Comment: @user2104710 - My simulation of the above circuit shows that with 24VDC feeding into the 30K resistor there is about 16 mW being dissipated in that component. So any resistor with a power rating above that will be suitable. Your 1W resistor will be just fine as long as you can live with its physical size.

Comment: Note that the circuit draws less than 1mA from the 24V supply.

Comment: It works. Heat in the 30K 1W is negliglble and I left it on for 24hours. Thanks for the help Michael Karas..and everyone :-)